# How to extract hyperlink from html anchor tag in pandas

Tags: dataframe

We have a field in dataframe having value as -

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>
```

I need to extract only `http://twitter.com/download/iphone` in pandas,

I tried using -

```
twitter_archive['source'].find('a')
```

to get starting index position, but its giving error :

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

How we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to extract domain name.

```
twitter_archive['source'].str.split("/").str[2]
```